# Find which parameters of stored procedures are nullable (optional)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I know I can use the following query to find all stored procedures and their parameters :

```
SELECT 
    r.*, p.*
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS r INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS AS p 
    ON r.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = p.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA AND r.SPECIFIC_NAME = p.SPECIFIC_NAME
WHERE     (r.ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE')
```

From this I can see (almost) all info about parameters, but I don't know how to find which of them are nullable or have default values.

Is there any way to find this?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All parameters are nullable. There is no syntax to specify that `NULL` should not be passed.

To find out those that have defaults you can inspect `sys.parameters` for CLR stored procedures

```
SELECT has_default_value,name
FROM sys.parameters
where object_id=object_id('YourProc')
```

Unfortunately this column [is not currently populated correctly](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=234143) for TSQL stored procedures and the only ways involve parsing the object definition.

Comment: Actually parameters are not nullable unless you declare them the be when creating the procedure e.g. parametername = null (assuming SQL Server)

Comment: @Tony that just gives them a default value of null if no value is supllied. You can pass an explicit value of null for **all** parameters. Example `EXEC('CREATE PROC usp_Foo @P1 INT AS SELECT @P1'); EXEC usp_Foo NULL`

Comment: Does that query work for determining whether a parameter has a default value?  As far as I can tell it will only work for CLR objects [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652361/determine-whether-sp-parameter-has-a-default-value-in-t-sql ]

Comment: @SanjayU - Yes you're correct. I just assumed `has_default_value` would do what it said on the tin.

Comment: Any clue where that issue originally in the "connect" link now resides?  This really seems like a trivial thing for MS to address, and I'd like to upvote the issue! :/

Comment: @JonathanB.   archived copy https://web.archive.org/web/20160702213604/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=234143 and migrated without the votes https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891455-populate-has-default-value-in-sys-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try this query to get all defaul values for specific stored procedure -

```
SELECT  
      data3.[object_name]
    , data3.name
    , [default_value] = REVERSE(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(
            data3.rtoken
        , CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(N',', data3.rtoken) > 0 
                THEN CHARINDEX(N',', data3.rtoken) + 1
            WHEN CHARINDEX(N')', data3.rtoken) > 0 
                THEN CHARINDEX(N')', data3.rtoken) + 1
            ELSE 1 
            END
        , LEN(data3.rtoken)
        )))
FROM (
    SELECT  
          data2.name
        , data2.[object_name]
        , rtoken = CASE WHEN data2.ptoken LIKE '%=%' 
            THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(ptoken
                        , CHARINDEX('=', ptoken, 1) + 1
                        , LEN(data2.ptoken))
                    )
            END
    FROM (
        SELECT  
              data.name
            , data.[object_name]
            , ptoken = SUBSTRING(
                    data.tokens
                , token_pos + name_length + 1
                , ISNULL(ABS(next_token_pos - token_pos - name_length - 1), LEN(data.tokens))
            )
        FROM (
            SELECT  
                  sm3.tokens
                , sm3.[object_name]
                , p.name
                , name_length = LEN(p.name)
                , token_pos = CHARINDEX(p.name, sm3.tokens)
                , next_token_pos = CHARINDEX(p2.name, sm3.tokens)
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                      sm2.[object_id]
                    , sm2.[object_name]
                    , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX('SA', sm2.tokens) + 2, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens))) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                          sm.[object_id]
                        , [object_name] = s.name + '.' + o.name
                        , tokens = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(
                                        sm.[definition]
                                    , CHARINDEX(o.name, sm.[definition]) + LEN(o.name) + 1
                                    , ABS(CHARINDEX(N'AS', sm.[definition]))
                                    )  
                        ) 
                    FROM sys.sql_modules sm WITH (NOLOCK)
                    JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
                    WHERE o.[type] = 'P '
                ) sm2
                WHERE sm2.tokens LIKE '%=%'
            ) sm3
            JOIN sys.parameters p WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm3.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
            OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT p2.name
                FROM sys.parameters p2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE p2.is_output = 0
                    AND sm3.[object_id] = p2.[object_id] 
                    AND p.parameter_id + 1 = p2.parameter_id
            ) p2
            WHERE p.is_output = 0
        ) data
    ) data2
) data3
```

Comment: Could you describe in English, at a general level, what this is doing?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank He is parsing the stored procedure text and trying to pick out the defaults. If i run this on my database, it returns a lot of incorrect information, so it's not quite ready for prime time.

Comment: @SimonHughes: I figured as much, but it's hard to make sense of the specifics.